# How to manage images for different storeviews?

Tags: magento2, product-images, admin-panel, gallery-image

Magento2 with 1 website and 2 storeviews `SV English` and `SV German`

**First thing** : I upload 5 images in `image uploading section` of product-page with setting `All Storeview` mode. Let's call image A, B, C, D and E. I do the upload, one by one, so they appear in the right sequence A,B,C,D,E. I save and they then magically appear in a different sequence (let's say A,C,E,D,B). I can drag and drop them to the required sequence, save and all OK.

Now if  I go to my German SV to update the necessary data `(not the images)` and I realized that the sequence was here different from the default one.

Is that a known issue? Is there a solution so that the sequence is applied to all Storeviews?

I also mention that if I hide/unhide an image in the `German SV`, it has no effect on the All storeviews even though the image Gallery attribute is set as Global.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Magento 2.1.8 ?

Comment: No, still in 2.1.6. Is that a known issue fixed in 2.1.8?

Comment: I know there is a known issue for the configurable option sorting but I am not aware for your issue. You can first try to upgrade to the last version of Magento 2.1.8. Try to reproduce with a vanilla installation. So you can create a github issue in Magento.

Comment: thanks, starting to regret to have choosen Magento 2 for our revamped website, 1 year after launch, still not stable...

Comment: There are still bugs, but it is open source, you can fix them.

Comment: thanks, I am unfortunately not skillful enough to solve it, I would love to learn but I am short in time to do so. anyway, the bugs are not deal breaker.